# JavaFX : Rotated animation delay between cycles

Tags: java, animation, javafx

I've created an animation for an ImageView based on a RotatedTranstion using the following code :

```
ImageView icon = ImageCache.getImage("refresh.png");
RotateTransition rotateTransition = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(2000), icon);
rotateTransition.setByAngle(360.0);
rotateTransition.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);

rotateTransition.play();
```

This results in the following animation :

[Rotation in Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2r2IP.gif)

As you may have noticed in the animated gif, the animation is not continuous i.e there is a small delay (pause) between animation cycles.

I've tried to look at the API but can't figure out what causes this delay and how i can get rid of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The apparent pause between each cycle is caused by the [interpolator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Transition.html#interpolatorProperty), which by default uses `Interpolator.EASE_BOTH` (so it decelerates at the end of each cycle and accelerates at the beginning).

To remove this, just set the interpolator to `Interpolator.LINEAR`:

```
rotateTransition.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! In fact i tried changing the interpolator to other values but never tried with Interpolator.LINEAR since i wronly believed it was the default one.

Comment: @PabloNavais Ugh, same. Why the heck isn't linear the default to begin with!

Comment: I guess `EASE_BOTH` looks better with `cycleCount` set to `1`, which is the default `cycleCount`. But I agree, `LINEAR` feels like a more natural default.

Answer (score 2):

The timing for acceleration and deceleration at each `Transition` cycle is controlled by the `Interpolator`. The default `Interpolator` used by Transition is `Interpolator.EASE_BOTH`.

You want **linear** interpolation so add this to your code:

```
rotateTransition.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ron !